# How initialize timezone in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, timezone, fullcalendar

For full calendar view, it is getting displayed currently on device local timezone. However, I want it to render dynamically as per timezone in which the person is viewing it. Is there a way to handle this?

Essentially, the person viewing the calendar should not be able to create an event on the current date or past dates in his timezone. And that is the reason it is required to make the person see full calendar in his timezone.

Comment: I would suggest to explore `[moment.js]`. Here's [link](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set timezone this way

```
jQuery('your-css-selector').fullCalendar({
 timezone: 'local'
});
```

According to the official Doc you can set to local timezone this way. I guess thats what you are looking for https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/

To disable a date you can use the DayRender option https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/dayRender/

```
jQuery('your-css-selector').fullCalendar({
 dayRender: (date, cell) => {
    if (date > youCurrentDate){
        jQuery(cell).addClass('disabled');
    }
 }
});
```

I assume you know how you can get the current date.